# PHP - PDO 'config' file equivalent

Tags: php, pdo

This may be a question that has been answered before - if so please just leave a comment below and I'll remove this one.

I have been learning classes in PHP and at the same time making the jump to PDO.

One concept I cant seem to find is how to acomplish the equivalent to this with classes:

***config.php***

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';

$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("MySQL Error");
mysql_select_db("account_db", $con);

?>
```

***another.php***

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');

$selectStatement = "SELET foo FROM bar";
$selectQuery = mysql_query($selectStatement, $con);

?>
```

I haven't quite figured out how I would create a config file/class for a PDO connection and then use it in another class, i.e. Users as below:

```
<?php

class Users
{
    private $_userId;

    function setUserId($username)
    {
        // Use a predefined database handle to connect to a database to get the users ID - I assume using a preconfigured $dbh handle via an include or extend?
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username");
        $sth->bindParam(':username', $username);
        ...
    }
}

?>
```

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my projects, I prefer using a class with a static member which holds the PDO object.

```
<?php
class DB
{
   private static $instance = null;
   public static function get()
   {
       if(self::$instance == null)
       {
           try
           {
               self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name', 'user', 'abc123');
           } 
           catch(PDOException $e)
           {
               // Handle this properly
               throw $e;
           }
       }
       return self::$instance;
   }
}
```

The I can access it like so:

```
<?php
require 'DB.php';
class Users
{
    private $_userId;

    function setUserId($username)
    {
        // Using DB::get() to get the PDO object
        $sth = DB::get()->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username");
        $sth->bindParam(':username', $username);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks spot on, so whereas I'd normally be creating the $dbh in the same file, simply require the database class and use `DB::get()->`. Does that work for all the commands PDO has to offer? (Please forgive my newbie slant with 'commands' - I haven't learnt all the syntax yet)

Comment: @lethalMango: Yup. It's returning an instance of `PDO`, so it's just like: `$x = new PDO(...); $x->prepare/lastInsertId/etc.();`

Comment: Just come back to my PDO/OOP tutorials Tim and used what you have above and have the following error: `"Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: DB::$instance in C:\wamp\www\mobileapi\api\database.php on line 7"`.. any ideas?

Comment: Found the problem, have revised the code. Was just a case of the private $instance not being static :) Works perfect, thanks again

Comment: Old I know... but just converting an old project to PDO and learning PHP objects in the process. This is awesome! A connector class rather than a function with horrible config variables. I always wished to be able to do something like this but didn't know how. Turns out objects are brilliant. So you've wrapped up all the DB connection code so it can be fired using in 1 line everywhere else. Need to add further stuff? Just change the class! Amazing - thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to make a dynamic variable in the get() function? So for example I could say `DB::get('read_only_user')`, and the the function will be written `public static function get($user)` and then I can use it based on different databases and which permissions are given..?

Comment: And due to the `private static $instance = null;` would I still be able to create multiple `public static functions` using this instance?

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted:  You would obviously have to modify the code a bit to support that, but it would be possible.  You would have to replace `private static $instance` with an associative array which would hold each "type" of database connection.

Comment: So would that be like: `private static $instance = array(
        'db1' => 'null', 'db2' => 'null'
    );` and then for each db connection ask: `if (self::$instance['db1'] == null) {` or what?

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted:  Yup, something like that.  You'll probably have to add more checking to ensure the requested type is valid.

Comment: Like what? Sorry for the many comments, bur I don't think there is a reason for posting a new question for this..

Comment: @TimCooper what do you think about that strategy nowadays? I mean, some developers always change their methods. I made a classe like yours, but some I'm not sure if it is the best way to do this.